# WP8 Version number is corrupt

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, version, corruption

I have an app that I uploaded through the microsoft dev portal and the version number was 1.1.0.7 but somehow got corrupted to a large number like 2015.626.1221.2028.

Ever since then when I do a build in visual studio I am forced to upload a version with a higher number. Then that number also changes once uploaded.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there anyway to fix this and get back to having a normal version number? The app is a c++ universal app.

Comment: Did you try [contacting support](http://www.bing.com/search?q=windows%20apps%20dev%20center%20support)?

Comment: In Windows 8.1 version number takes automatically you can't do anything for that.

Comment: Yes, I contacted support and they essentially said what KiShOrE said. But if that is true then why does everyone else s app show a normal version number? If I look on any app page the version will be like 1.x.x.x not something that appears to be based on the date.